# how to replace mousedown event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, mouseevent

I want to display a popup on mousedown. It works fine in desktop and android. But in iOS it dosen't work. Is there any other event to be used instead of `mousedown` ?

Comment: Have you tried using the jquery-mobile library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I duplicate the function that has `$(document).mousedown(function(e)`  and replaced with this `$(document).bind('touchend', function(e)`  and it's working now